# How can we make a single dimension array to multidimensional Hierarchical?

Tags: php, loops, multidimensional-array

I have an single array of Hierarchical categories. Index of the array is the category_id like::

```
[8846] => Array
    (
        [category_id] => 8846
        [title] => Tsting two
        [description] => Tsting two
        [subtype] => categories
        [type] => object
        [level] => 2
        [parent_category] => 8841
        [tags] => new
        [name] => Tsting two
    )
```

each value has its parent_category value, I have around 500 elements in the array, what is the best way to make it.

Process i followed:

krsort categories array, so that all the child categories are at the beginning, then

```
function makeHierarchical() {
  foreach($this->categories as $guid => $category) {
    if($category['level'] != 1)
    $this->multilevel_categories[$category['parent_category']][$guid] = $category;
}
```

}

but this is not working, it does it only for first level.

Can someone point out me the error.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892676#2892821

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use the answer I posted yesterday to a similar question:

> > [Convert a series of parent-child relationships into a hierarchical tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915748/how-can-i-convert-a-series-of-parent-child-relationships-into-a-hierarchical-tree/2915920#2915920)

Essentially it's the same, you just have more fields in your arrays. Basically you need to traverse the array recursively.

Comment: Thanks for the help, can you please tell me where was i doing mistake in my code