# How to create Hierarchical Links for Sitemap.html

Tags: php, sitemap

I need to create a HTML sitemap similar to apple.com/sitemap with Parent Category and sub category under it. I have created two tables as such:
Primary Category:

> ID  | TITLE | URL

Sub Category as:

> ID|Parent_Category_ID|TITLE|URL
>   ...

How do i retrieve it so that it shows something like:

Parent_Category

- Sub_Cat
- Sub_Cat

Edit:
Followed some online suggestions, so now there is one table:

```
ID      Parent       Name        URL
1          0         Parent1     URL1
2          0         Parent2     URL2  
3          1         Sub1        URL3
4          0         Parent3     URL4
5          2         Sub2        URL5
```

Here is the code using which I'm able to generate an array of categories with sub categories

```
<?php

   include('config.php');   



echo '<pre>';

$categories = Sitemap::getTopCategories();
print_r($categories);

echo '</pre>';

class Sitemap
{ 


public static function getTopCategories()
{
    return self::getCategories('parent = 0');
}

public static function getCategories($where = '')
{
    if ($where) $where = " WHERE $where";
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM testing $where");

    $categories = array();

    while ($category = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $my_id = $category['id'];
    $category['children'] = Sitemap::getCategories("parent = $my_id");
            $categories[] = $category;
        }

    mysql_free_result($result);
    return $categories;
  }
 }
 ?>
```

Now what I have to follow so that it displays in a proper way as of apple.com/sitemap. I' ready with the CSS for proper placement however not able to display it.

Please Help!!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @Event_Horizon: I have updated the changes, please go through it and kindly help me

Comment: Please be more specific. Instead of showing us a wall of script.

Comment: How to show the generated array in a hierarchical order of <ul> and <li>..

Comment: here is a link to the generated array and how i want it to display: http://pastebin.com/6JZTQa34

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function I used to get the array in a proper format..

```
function outputCategories($categories, $startingLevel = 0)  
{

    foreach ($categories as $key => $category)
    {
        if (count($category['children']) > 0)
        {
            echo '<li><a title="'.$category['name'].'" href="'.$category['url'].'">'.$category['name'].'</a><ul>';
            outputCategories($category['children'], $startingLevel+1);
            echo "</li>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<li><a title="'.$category['name'].'" href="'.$category['url'].'">'.$category['name'].'</a></li>';
        }
    }
    echo "</ul>";
    return self;
}
```

For more info refer this post: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794638/turn-database-result-into-array)