# Codeigniter - how to run multiple/batch queries?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a bunch of queries that are generated by a shell script on one server and are to be consumed by a CI app on another server. The queries run fine when run individually but fail when run as a batch. Is there any way out? Please note that these are not multiple inserts or updates and queries may span more than one line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a limitation of CodeIgniter but rather of the database client libraries.

I.e., `mysql_query()` can only execute a single query at a time.

Depending on the client, there are alternatives,

I.e., `mysqli_multi_query()`

Comment: CI doesn't let you override db class :(

Comment: Which db client is it using? Mysql? Mysqli? If it truly not flexible enough and you are stuck with a client that does not support multiple queries, then you are simply left with having to execute each query individually.

Comment: Thanks a ton John! This is how I fixed it `mysqli_multi_query($this->db->conn_id, $sql);` where `$sql` has batch SQL commands. Apart from this unseen issue I just had to build MDBTools from source. Thanks!