# Is it possible to run a long .sql file through Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, codeigniter

I want to run a `.sql` file from my server in Codeigniter 3.1.0. I have tried following

```
//code to create a DB & this is successful then following ocde 
$query = file_get_contents('./test.sql');
$this->db->query($query);
```

Here is my `test.sql` file. https://gist.github.com/rejoan/97dfae1b08116e386b3e6fda97eeb4f7

Now when I run this it shows error always

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'CREATE TABLE `user` ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL, `test_id` int(11)
>   NOT NULL, `' at line 10

```
CREATE TABLE `test` 
( `id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`name` varchar(250) NOT NULL, 
`description` text NOT NULL, 
`added` date NOT NULL, 
`outdate` date NOT NULL 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; 

CREATE TABLE `user` 
( `id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`test_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
`name` varchar(250) NOT NULL 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; 

ALTER TABLE `test` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
ADD UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`);

ALTER TABLE `user` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
ADD KEY `test_id` (`test_id`); 

ALTER TABLE `test` MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=37; 

ALTER TABLE `user` MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT; 

ALTER TABLE `user` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_user_test` FOREIGN KEY (`test_id`) 
REFERENCES `test` (`id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

> Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/spider_clients/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

So how can I resolve this by issue? I have a idea to do this by PHP raw code but Firstly I want to solve by CI. Any Idea?

** Even I have tried by replacing all backtick by single quote still not works

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156828/codeigniter-how-to-run-multiple-batch-queries

Comment: so Ci solutions on this issue?

Comment: Well, as you said you need plain-CI solution. My link does not provide it. I hope it will help you to understand the idea of the problem.

Comment: maybe interesting? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027769/running-mysql-sql-files-in-php

Comment: I don't think you can run *multiple* queries in one statement.  You may need to break this up and call `->query()` multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

You can't run *any* SQL file through the API. Not even if you split up the file and run one query per API call.

There are some commands that can appear in SQL files, but they're actually [mysql client builtin commands](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-commands.html). These commands are not recognized by the SQL parser in the server.

It's tricky to split up the SQL file. There are SQL statements that contain literal semicolons, like `CREATE TRIGGER`. So you need more complex logic to split up the file, it's not as simple as [`preg_split('/;/', $query)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

Another gotcha: you'll find that submitting a "query" that consists of nothing but an SQL comment causes an error.

Also, if your SQL file is too large, you'll blow out PHP's max memory if you use `file_get_contents()`.

The bottom line is that you'll waste a lot of your time developing this code and trying to make it work. You're better off leveraging the tool that is already designed to run SQL scripts:

```
shell_exec("mysql databasename < ./test.sql");
```

See also:

- [Running MySQL *.sql files in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4028289/20860)

Comment: +upvote. Yes I have already seen this. Finally I have to use this as there no CI solutions