# INSERT Batch, and if duplicate key Update in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter, bulkinsert, batch-updates

Is there any way of performing in batch Insert query and if the key already exists, UPDATE that row in codeigniter?
I have gone through the documentation and found only insert_batch and update_batch. But how to update the row with duplicate key in active records? And what happens if one row fails to be inserted or updated in batch_insert? All insertion fails or only that row?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10372550/1239506

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will have to go with little custom query by adding "ON DUPLICATE" statement

```
$sql = $this->db->insert_string('YourTable', $data) . ' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE duplicate=duplicate+1';
$this->db->query($sql);
$id = $this->db->insert_id();
```

Also please [check this out](http://web.archive.org/web/20090221091226/http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/80958/), it will give you better solution

Answer (score 0):

For Codeigniter 3, you can use this library. This allows you to be able to supply an array of key-value pairs to be inserted into separate rows and will auto-update data if a duplicate key occurs in DB.
https://github.com/amir-ranglerz/CodeIgniter-Insert-Batch-on-DUPLICATE-KEY-Update